# How to convert numpy record array of bools to integers in order to calculate covariance?

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I have a record array of some half million entries with about 40 dimensions.  The dimensions are a mixture of datatypes.  I'd like to sub-select 5 boolean dimensions and take blocks of about 1k entries then calculate a covariance matrix to see dimensional correlations.  I am totally stuck on how to use `.view()` or `.astype()` to do this conversion.  The initial sub-selection:

```
p_new[['no_gender', 'no_age', 'no_income', 'no_politics', 'no_edu']]
array([(False, False, True, False, False), (True, True, False, True, True),
       (True, True, False, True, True), ...,
       (True, True, True, True, True), (True, True, True, True, True),
       (True, True, True, True, True)], 
      dtype=[('no_gender', '|b1'), ('no_age', '|b1'), ('no_income', '|b1'), ('no_politics', '|b1'), ('no_edu', '|b1')])
```

All my conversion attempts collapse my 5 dimensions down to 1 (unwanted!), so rather than going from `(1000,5) dtype=np.bool` to `(1000,5) dtype=np.int32` I end up with `(1000,1) dtype=np.int32`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to convert the booleans to integers at all.  In Python, `True` and `False` are actually subclasses of `int`, so you can simply do all the mathematical operations on them as normal.  `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`.

Proof:

```py
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True
>>> isinstance(False, int)
True
>>> (True + True * 3) / (True + False)
4
```

Though I will admit, I am not 100% sure about `numpy` datatypes and how that might come into play with what you're trying to do.

#### Update

Looking into `numpy` datatypes a little bit more, they do seem to exhibit similar--but not identical--behavior.  `numpy.bool` literally is the same as `bool`, it's just the standard Python boolean, so it definitely exhibits all the same behavior and can be used as integers.  However, `numpy.int32` is separately subclassed from `int`, so `isinstance(numpy.bool(1), numpy.int32)` naturally evaluates to `False`.  Maybe you'll have less trouble just going straight to `int`/`numpy.int`?

Comment: numpy types != python types, so I'm not sure this holds.  Several numpy matrix/vector operations seem to be upset when I pass in booleans.  In any case, I'm almost positive I've got to get the record-array into a standard ndarray with a single data type.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is that you operate on the whole row when you change the type. 
If you view as an array of bool, you get all the values, and then you can do `astype`. However you must reshape.

```
pnew.view("bool").astype(int).reshape(len(pnew),-1)
```

Easier is to use `.tolist()`, but might use more memory and might be slower.

```
asarray(pnew.tolist()).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that in a recarray each record is treated as a single element, ie for the following array the shape is (3,) not (3, 5).

```
A = np.array([('joe', 44, True, True, False),
              ('jill', 22, False, False, False),
              ('Jack', 21, True, False, True)],
             dtype=[['name', 'S4'], ['age', int], ['x', bool],
                    ['y', bool], ['z', bool]])
print A.shape
# (3,)
```

The easiest way to do what you're asking for is probably something like:

```
tmp = [A[field] for field in ['x', 'y', 'z']]
tmp = np.array(tmp, dtype=int)
```

You might also be able to use views, but using views for arrays with mixed data types can get kind of tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new dtype and than use `a.astype(new_dtype)`:

```
In [44]: a
Out[44]: 
array([(False, False, True, False, False), (True, True, False, True, True),
       (True, True, False, True, True), (True, True, True, True, True),
       (True, True, True, True, True), (True, True, True, True, True)], 
      dtype=[('no_gender', '|b1'), ('no_age', '|b1'), 
             ('no_income', '|b1'), ('no_politics', '|b1'), ('no_edu', '|b1')])

In [45]: new_dtype = np.dtype([(name, np.int) for name in a.dtype.names])

In [46]: a.astype(new_dtype)
Out[46]: 
array([(0, 0, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
       (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)], 
      dtype=[('no_gender', '<i8'), ('no_age', '<i8'), ('no_income', '<i8'),
             ('no_politics', '<i8'), ('no_edu', '<i8')])
```